# HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-16.04, linode

> /var/log/apache2/error.log:[Thu Jul 12 14:52:47.565151 2018]
>   [proxy:error] pid 29746:tid 139938330822400Connecti on refused:
>   AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to [::1]:3001 (localhost) failed
>   /var/log/apache2/error.log:[Thu Jul 12 14:52:47.565213 2018]
>   [proxy:error] [pid 29746:tid 139938330822400] AH00959: app
>   roxyconnectbackend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s
>   /var/log/apache2/error.log:[Thu Jul 12 14:52:47.565220 2018]
>   [proxyhttp:error] [pid 29746:tid 139938330822400] [client
>   123.136.118.89:31478] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: https://sizzia.com/login. html
>   /var/log/apache2/error.log:[Thu Jul 12 14:52:50.786689 2018]
>   [proxy:error] [pid 29746:tid 139938435008256] AH00940: HTTP : disabled
>   connection for (localhost)

**things checked:**
1)apache2 is active
2) ps aux | grep node" result:

son 30660 0.0 0.0 14224 936 ttyS0 S+ 15:14 0:00 grep --color=auto node

**Process**
-user able to log in into dashboard

**Current result**
-browser gave output 503
-maintain in log in page

background process is not working and browser show 503 error service unavailable.. did googling and still not working..

Comment: did any one have an answer for this?

Comment: i resolve this by start another server which is used proxy to https.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with `docker-composer.yml` port settings. I downloaded Wordpress docker ready version and did not notice the port settings were different to what I am used to.
Here is what I had (-) and what I changed (+) to fix it:

```
-      - ${IP}:8100:80 # before fix
+      - 8100:80       # after fix !!!
```

This command led me to the solution of the issue: `netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports`.

Before fix:

```
me@digitalocean:~$ netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:8100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

me@digitalocean:~$ nc -vz localhost 8100
nc: connect to localhost port 8100 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

After fix:

```
me@digitalocean:~$ netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8100               [::]:*                  LISTEN 

me@digitalocean:~$ nc -vz localhost 8100
Connection to localhost 8100 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

To restart docker don't forget to `docker-composer down; docker-composer up -d`